# Iframe Alternative?

Tags: html, iframe

I was just wondering if there was an Iframe alternative. I tried using a `div` with the following CSS:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and the `div`:

```
<div>
    <?php
        include "http://mydomainhere.com";
    ?>
</div>
```

But it seems like I can only use files in the `include()`. Can I use domains? If not, what it an alternative that I can?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Instead of using include() try to use file_get_contents() ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it is considered dangerous and is disabled by default.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: It also burdens your server with the bandwidth needed BOTH to fetch the content of http://mydomainhere.com and then to send it out to your visitor.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the content of the file to be displayed in the section.

try:

`<div>
    <?php
        echo file_get_contents("http://mydomainhere.com");
    ?>
</div>`